# What is the minimum Java code snipped that interrupts a function without generating unreachable code compilation errors

Tags: java

I would like to debug some code in order to study some behaviour (and introduce some forced errors in the execution). I would like to either throw exceptions or return earlier from functions before they complete. But, by using `throw` or `return` (as pointed by user @user15244370  in a comment below) generating unreachable code is a compilation error.

Currently I am using this snippet to avoid the detection of unreachable code:

```
if (Math.random() < 1) {
    throw new RuntimeException("This is an experiment.");
}
```

Is there a more compact form of such forced control flow interruption?

Comment: Not very clear. How do you want to test it? The code that breaks the flow cannot be dead code itself (unless another condition makes it so)

Comment: `if (false)` or `if (true)`? I somehow use this fast and dirty form - _don't try this at home_

Comment: Different tools might do very different checking. I am sure that there are some IntelliJ inspections that detect forms of dead code that plain javac doesnt see. So the question of your title renders it "out of scope" aka "off topic" for me. Do not expect us to tell you something that is true for any tool **you** intend to use.

Comment: usage of `if (true)` or `if (false)`, even using constant expressions  (e.g. `static final` field), is kind of documented in [JLS 14.22](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22)

Comment: @ernest_k Check the question know if it is more clear.

Comment: @GhostCat This is a tool agnostic question that doesn't care if Eclipse, InteliJ IDEA, Maven, etc. Just plain Java compilation.

Comment: Why are you not using mocks or fakes to short-circuit your execution?

Comment: How is it tools agnostic when tool A doesn't react the way tool B does?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

```java
x();

// or if you want to specify your own exception:

y(() -> new RuntimeException("..."));
```

I omitted the boilerplate:

```java
import static foo.Bar.*;

// and:

public class Bar {
  public static void x() {
    if(true) { // this will just give a dead code warning, no error
      // alternative: 1==1
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
  }

  public static void y(Supplier<RuntimeException> s) {
    if(...) {
      throw s.get();
    }
  }
}
```

To omit the warning you can use a more complex expression, like `"".equals("")`

Comment: The main point of this answer was: Use a static helper function. Then it can be a lot shorter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Eclipse**, then in debug mode you could,

1. Add a conditional breakpoint and add the required code there.
2. Open the `Debug Shell` view and write the required code there and once the debugger reaches your point of interest, select the code in the debug shell and then : `right click -> force return`

I would suggest the first approach because in the second approach, you need to select the piece of code and do a force return each time the breakpoint is reached. But in the case of conditional breakpoints it is mostly an one time process.

You could add the random exception code as the condition of the breakpoint:

```java
if (Math.random() < 1) {
    throw new RuntimeException("This is an experiment.");
}

return false;
```

The conditional breakpoint feature is available in most of the IDEs.

Comment: Not using Eclipse in my case, but indeed this is what I want to achieve. What I also want to do is being able to throw random Exceptions at some points i the code.

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay that is also possible inside a conditional breakpoint. (I have updated my answer)